# How to get login activity of users?

Tags: mysql

I've a table names loginActivity which stores user ids & login time. I want to count how many times a user logged in the system. You may say it user retention. If a user logs in two or more times a day this will be valued as 1 not 2/3.

I'm having problem with MySQL.

Please check the Table info below 
[image]

I have tried several times. But query didn't succeed. 
SAMPLE QUERY:

`select sender_id, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(sender_id)) FROM messages  where created_at < '2020-01-26' ) from messages where created_at < '2020-01-26' GROUP BY sender_id HAVING(COUNT(sender_id) > 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want for each user to get a number of days in which the user logged in at least once. You can achieve this by grouping by user id and counting distinct days:

```
SELECT t.uid, COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(t.logindate))
FROM tablename t
GROUP BY t.uid
```

Comment: YES. Thanks Sir. Didn't try with logindate. It works :)